request focus not working after few time with setState Flutter
here is my code
  late FocusNode fcMa, fcViTri;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fcMa = FocusNode();
    fcViTri = FocusNode();
    fcMa.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    fcMa.dispose();
    fcViTri.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            focusNode: fcMa,
            onSubmitted: (value)=> fcViTri.requestFocus(),
          ),
          TextField(
            focusNode: fcViTri,
            onSubmitted: (value) async {
              callApi().then((value) {
                setState(() {
                  //clear all text field
                  fcMa.requestFocus();
                });
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


What can I do now, it work well for few time then suddently not showing up.
init it will focus to the fcMa then call onSubmit to focus the 2nd. Then go back to 1st textfiled by call onSubmit of the 2nd TextFiled.
Then after few time like that, the focus didn`t work anymore ?
How to fix this

Any help here. Im still stuck with this
